# Add a form field to a child form in symfony

Tags: forms, symfony4

Symfony 4.1

This is my personal form type:

```
class PersonalType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstName', TextType::class, [
                'required' => true,
                'attr'     => [
                    'placeholder' => 'First name'
                ],
            ])
    //......
```

This is my ClientType using PersonalType as a child form

```
    class ClientType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
      $client = $builder->getData();
        $builder
            ->add('personalDetails', PersonalType::class, [
                'data' => $client
            ])
//....
```

I have added an event listener to the child form type but this doesn't get called, so I moved the eventlistener to the ClientType.

I wanted to add a field to PersonalType and I have done so like this:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
          $client = $event->getData();
          $form = $event->getForm();

$form->add('title', TextType::class, [
   'type' => new PersonType(),
    'label' => 'Title'
]
    }
```

but I've got an error saying `option "type" does not exists`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The ['type' => ...] option is not a valid option of Symfony's TextType. See the reference here for the valid options: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html. You can also see the valid options of the other build-in form types here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html.

Maybe you've seen a custom form type which defines the "type" option by having a `configurationOptions` method with a `setDefaults` or `setRequired` (see here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html). I'm guessing that's from your PersonType. TextType doesn't support that.

I'm not sure what exactly you wish to do with the

```
   'type' => new PersonType(),
```

line. If you're just trying to add the "title" field to your PersonType, and for some reason you want to do it with an event listener rather than directly in the PersonType class (which would be the simplest option in most scenarios), it feels like just removing that line would be enough to make it work?